# Are Steam achievements also given in journey mode?

Tags: steam, achievements, terraria

Since "Journey's End" release (patch 1.4+) there is a new journey mode with togglable god-mode and difficulty meter.

Is it possible for a new player to play in journey mode and get all achievements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can earn achievements while in Journey Mode. I'm not entirely sure if all of them are achievable, however I can confirm that I received a few achievements (Vehicular Manslaughter, Benched) from a Journey Mode world. I don't see any achievements specifically relating to Master Mode either, so I would imagine you can achieve everything in Journey Mode.